# How to test hypothesis with multiple 'or' restictions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, linear-model, multiple-comparisons, restrictions

I am seeking help to interpret a question and set up test procedures for a series of hypotheses (six in total, two of which I can answer). It is part of a weekly problem set we are given in class. The question is repeated verbatim below:

Suppose that we have a consistent estimator $\hat{\theta}$ for a K $\times$ 1 vector of model parameters $\theta$ with

$\sqrt{N}(\hat{\theta}-\theta) \sim N(0,\Sigma)$

where N is the number of observations and $\Sigma$ is nonsingular.

1. If $K=1$, how do you test the following hypothesis:

   $H_0 : \theta = 0$ and $\theta = -1$
2. If $K=2$, how do you test the following hypothesis:

   $H_0 : \theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2 = 0$
3. If $K=1$, how do you test the following hypothesis:

   $H_0 : \theta = 1$ or $\theta = -1$
4. If $K=2$, how do you test the following hypothesis:

$
H_0: = \left\{\begin{aligned}
& \theta_1 = 1 \text{ or } \theta_1 = -1 &&\\
&\theta_2 = 1 \text{ or } \theta_1 = -2 &&
\end{aligned}
\right.$

5. If $K=1$, how do you test the following hypothesis:

   $H_0 : \theta = 1$ or $\theta = 2$ or $\theta = 3$
6. If $K=3$, how do you test the following hypothesis:

   $H_0 : \theta_1 = 1$ or $\theta_1 = -1$ or $\theta_1\theta_2^2 = 2$ or $\theta_1\theta_3 = 2$

We need to note the method we'd use, formulate the test statistic, and note it's distribution. For example, I think I can solve the second one. It can be simplified by noting it is the same as imposing the two linear restrictions $\theta_1=\theta_2=0$. Then we calculate the Wald statistic:

$W = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \hat{\theta_1} & \hat{\theta_2} \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \left(\frac{\Sigma}{N}\right)^{-1}$ $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \hat{\theta_1} \\ \hat{\theta_2} \end{smallmatrix})$

Which will have a chi-square distribution with two degrees of freedom. 
I also think I know the answer to the first one - it can't be solved (It is testing two restrictions with only one variable, and so the R matrix wouldn't have full row rank).

But for the others I am genuinely stumped. I have never seen 'or' restrictions before. It doesn't make sense to me - how can I test if the same parameter is equal to one of two different values? What would the restriction matrix (as in the $R$ in $R\theta - q = 0$) look like?

I am seeking guidance, or an example solution to one of the tests, so I have somewhere to start.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you received any feedback from your class or TA ? I would be curious to know the answer, cheers